# What is the best Open Source Web Crawler Tool written in Java?

Tags: java, web-crawler

What is the best Open Source Web Crawler Tool, written in Java.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [crawler4j](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/). You just need to implement a simple interface which controls which URLs to visit and what to do with each crawled page.

Comment: I have problems crawling HTTPS websites using this crawler ("site failed to respond" while it opens fine in browser etc.)

Answer (score 5):

in java I think it boils down to [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) vs [Heritrix](https://webarchive.jira.com/wiki/display/Heritrix/Heritrix). You should specify what your needs are to get a better answer.